# Como encontrar o nome e endereço dos alunos e professores de São Paulo

Tags: sql, oracle

Olá, estou com uma dúvida na questão que meu professor passou para treinar. O banco de dados possui 5 tabelas sendo: uma `alunos`, `professores` e `historico` no exercício pede para consultar nome e endereço dos alunos e professores de *São Paulo*, porém a maneira qual estou resolvendo retorna todos os alunos do professor que mora em São Paulo e se o aluno morar em São Paulo retorna os professores que esse residam em outra cidade.

Informação sobre as tabelas:

```
create table Alunos ( 
ra number(9) constraint ra_pk primary key, 
nm_aluno varchar(30) constraint nm_aluno_nn not null, 
endereco varchar(50), 
cidade varchar(30) 
);


create table Professores ( 
cod_prof number(9) constraint cod_prod_pk primary key, 
nm_prof varchar(50) constraint nm_prof_nn not null,  
endereco_prof varchar(50), 
cidade_prof varchar(30) 
);

create table Historico ( 
ra number(9) constraint ra_fk references Alunos 
             constraint ra_nn not null, 
cod_disc number(5) constraint cod_disc_fk_tr references Disciplinas 
                   constraint cod_disc_nn_tr not null, 
cod_turma number(5) constraint cod_turma_fk references Turma, 
cod_prof number(9) constraint cod_prof_fk_tr references Professores 
                   constraint cod_prof_nn_tr not null, 
ano_tr number(4), 
frequencia number(4), 
nota number(2) 
);

insert into Alunos values (945441422,'Wesley Junior Francisco','Rua Renato Marques Jr','Minas Gerais');
insert into Alunos values (955655481,'Gustavo Dias Rodrigue','Rua Mato Grosso','São Paulo');
insert into Alunos values (458586521,'Lucas Ferreira Silva','Rua Benedicto de Souza Branco','Rio de Janeiro');
insert into Alunos values (686955654,'Ana Vicari Beatriz','Rua Rangel Pestana', 'São Paulo');
insert into Alunos values (326546985,'Yasmim Santos','Rua Macapá','São Paulo');
insert into Alunos values (963258741,'Geraldo Francisco Farias','Rua Cisne','Guarulhos');
insert into Alunos values (654987321,'Clarice Jaqueline','Avenida Contorno','Guarulhos');
insert into Alunos values (845621789,'Vinicius Murilo Gomes','SES 801 Lote 05','Brasília'); 
insert into Alunos values (541258963,'Bryan Arthur Gonçalves','Rua 3 de Setembro','Manaus'); 
insert into Alunos values (852654951,'Aurora Heloisa','Rua Antonio de Godoi','São Paulo'); 
insert into Alunos values (741489951,'Cauã Eduardo Vicente Peixoto','Rua A','Palmeira dos Índios');
insert into Alunos values (951654753,'Adriana Laura','Rua Rio Brilhante','São Luís');
insert into Alunos values (357963369,'Miguel Gustavo','Rua Carolina Lopes de Faria','Garulhos');
insert into Alunos values (963987951,'Alana Rayssa Caroline Fogaça','Quadra Orla 14 Alameda 7','Santos');
insert into Alunos values (456456456,'Elza Daiane Assunção','Quadra SHCES Quadra 611 Área Especial s/n','Palmas');
insert into Alunos values (541523587,'Luzia Clara Cavalcanti','Praça Humberto Mendes','Goiânia');

insert into Professores values(789456123,'Vania Cristina','Rua Brás Pina','São Paulo');
insert into Professores values(852963741,'Marcel Thomé','1ª Travessa Beira Rio','Rio de Janeiro');
insert into Professores values(147852369,'Alice Flora','Avenida Brasil','Rio de Janeiro');
insert into Professores values(578951258,'Wagner Luiz','Travessa Treze de Abril','São Paulo');
insert into Professores values(951753698,'Maria Cristina','Avenida Jundiaí','Jundaí');  

insert into Historico values(945441422,12366,14785,789456123,2010,15,4);
insert into Historico values(955655481,32145,14765,852963741,2010,100,5);
insert into Historico values(458586521,45612,25851,147852369,2011,25,7);
insert into Historico values(686955654,45612,32145,578951258,2000,35,5);
insert into Historico values(326546985,51234,32154,951753698,2018,55,5);
insert into Historico values(963258741,44566,14785,789456123,2015,6,6);
insert into Historico values(654987321,44566,14765,852963741,2010,45,8);
insert into Historico values(845621789,45612,25851,147852369,2011,8,10);
insert into Historico values(541258963,51234,32145,578951258,2000,1,10);
insert into Historico values(852654951,51234,32154,951753698,2018,10,6);
insert into Historico values(741489951,44566,14785,789456123,2010,5,1);
insert into Historico values(951654753,12366,14765,852963741,2011,6,3);
insert into Historico values(357963369,32145,25851,147852369,2012,52,6);
insert into Historico values(963987951,45612,32145,578951258,2013,92,9);
insert into Historico values(456456456,51234,32154,951753698,2014,65,2);
insert into Historico values(541523587,44566,14785,789456123,2017,4,8);
```

---

Método que eu utilizei, mas não é o correto :

```
select nm_prof, endereco_prof,cidade_prof nm_aluno,endereco from historico h inner join alunos a on h.ra=a.ra inner join professores p on h.cod_prof=p.cod_prof where cidade = 'São Paulo' or cidade_prof='São Paulo'
```

Resultado está anexado como imagem.
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter conseguido expressar minha dúvida e agraço quem conseguir sana-lá.

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta... é pra retornar todos os alunos dos professores que residem em são paulo?

Comment: O que voce quer apenas os alunos e professor que moram em São Paulo?

Comment: E se você trocar o OR do `where cidade = 'São Paulo' or cidade_prof='São Paulo'` por `and`?

Comment: Se você quer todos os moradores de São Paulo, sejam professores ou sejam alunos, então utilize UNION. Selecione todos os alunos que moram em São Paulo e faça a união com todos os professores que moram em São Paulo.

Comment: Olá Lucas, gostaria de saber se a minha resposta tem o ajudado

Answer (score 0):

*Bem vindo ao StackOverFlow!*

Pelo que entendi analisando sua pergunta e o resultado de sua query adicionada como imagem, acredito que você queira o resultado de apenas os alunos que residem em São Paulo **e** também apenas os professores que residem em São Paulo.

Sua consulta atualmente está assim:

```
SELECT nm_prof,
       endereco_prof,
       cidade_prof nm_aluno,
       endereco 
FROM historico h 
INNER JOIN alunos a
    ON h.ra = a.ra 
INNER JOIN professores p
    ON h.cod_prof = p.cod_prof 
WHERE cidade = 'São Paulo' or cidade_prof='São Paulo'
```

Analisando sua consulta vi 3 situações inconsistentes:

1. Note que no seu anexo a coluna NM_ALUNO está trazendo o estado do professor, isso porque ao declarar na consulta acima você trouxe o valor da coluna e deu um alias pra ele no código à seguir: `... cidade_prof nm_aluno, ...`. Este código está sem a separação por virgulas, então o SGBD entende que os valores referentes à coluna cidade_prof serão nomeados no prompt de saída como nm_aluno.
2. Se você apenas quer trazer os alunos e professores em que **AMBOS** são de São Paulo, você utilizará a cláusula **AND** ao invés de **OR** nessa parte `WHERE cidade = 'São Paulo' AND cidade_prof='São Paulo'`
3. A terceira e ultima situação é uma dica que lhe dou: Após o SELECT, note que você esta referenciando colunas da tabela de professor(as 3 primeiras colunas) e aluno(ultima coluna), porém, para facilitar na manutenção do código adicione o alias da tabela como prefixo da chamada, como por exemplo: `SELECT p.nm_prof, p.endereco_prof, p.cidade_prof, a.m_aluno, a.endereco ...` isso facilita a sua vida ou do próximo que irá fazer a manutenção na query.

Bons estudos.